# How a long data type will be stored in a memory?

Tags: c, performance, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

**My Need:**

For any non - negative unsigned long a,

> Input a = 5;    Ans should be  3
>
> Input a = 12;   Ans should be 4
>
> Input a = 1;    Ans should be  1
>
> Input a=0    Ans should be 0
>
> i.e to Find the most significant 1 position from the left.

**What I have tried:**

```
int count = 0;

if( a!=0 )
 do{
   count++;
 }while( a >>= 1 );
```

**Problem** 
  Takes more time because of while loop and shifting.

**Proposed method**
  If I know how the 4 bytes is stored in memory, (using char*) I will take out the byte, which contains the most significant 1, thus in worst case maximum 8 shifting will suffice to find the answer.

Comment: Sure you need to worry about that tiny bit of speed? Whatever you're using to print the results will take a lot more time to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Your method won't work if the most significant byte doesn't contain the bit you're looking for (i. e. if your number is less than `2 ^ (3 * CHAR_BIT)`). Why don't you just start from the other end?

```
unsigned find_msb(unsigned long long n)
{
    int bits_max = sizeof(n) * CHAR_BIT - 1;
    int i;
    for (i = bits_max; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((n >> i) & 1) return i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. I will check as *p != 0 , if the no is less than 2^ 24, then this condition fails thus I will check the next most significant byte. find_msb will be too long for lower values of n like 1,2 etc...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are way to worried about efficiency. Worst case is O(n) and frankly it's never going to get any better. Even in an embedded system on a slow processor there's no real need to try and speed up H2CO3's algorithm.

Get it working, then worry about efficiency.